# How to ignore some words when counting the frequency of a word accuracy in a text?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, pandas, scikit-learn

How can I ignore some words like 'a', 'the', when counting the frequency of a word accuracy in a text?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df= pd.DataFrame({'phrase': pd.Series('The large distance between cities. The small distance. The')})
f = CountVectorizer().build_tokenizer()(str(df['phrase']))

result = collections.Counter(f).most_common(1)

print result
```

The answer will be **The**. But I would like to get **distance** as the most frequent word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be best to avoid counting the entries to begin with like so.

```
ignore = {'the','a','if','in','it','of','or'}
result = collections.Counter(x for x in f if x not in ignore).most_common(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the `stop_words` parameter of `CountVectorizer`.
These are words that you are not interested in and will be discarded by the analyzer.

```
f = CountVectorizer(stop_words={'the','a','if','in','it','of','or'}).build_analyzer()(str(df['phrase']))
result = collections.Counter(f).most_common(1)
print result
[(u'distance', 1)]
```

Note that the `tokenizer` does not perform preprocessing (lowercasing, accent-stripping) or remove stop words, so you need to use the analyzer here.

You can also use `stop_words='english'` to automatically remove english stop words (see `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS` for the full list).